# Strange gd warning

Tags: php, exception, gd

I have a feature where users can upload pictures. It works well in all tests and a large amount of users are using it without problems. However, in some rare cases I see some warnings in the logs, which I do not really understand.

This line is running after the picture is uploaded:

```
//...
                        switch ($imageType) {
                            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
                                break;
                            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                                $image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
                                break;
                            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                                $image = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
                                break;
                            case IMAGETYPE_BMP:
                                $image = imagecreatefromwbmp($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
                                break;
                            default :
                                return false;
                        }
//...
```

and in some very rare cases I cannot reproduce I get this warning:

> Exception 'PHPErrorException' with message 'Warning [2]
>   imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png: fatal libpng error: IDAT: CRC error line

I have googled this exception and found [this page](https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/10500), however, I cannot reproduce problems with image manipulation and there are no folder permission problems, so the answers do not apply to my case.

Question: What is the meaning of this error?

Comment: this means, the CRC check fails on an IDAT chunk. have a look at the PNG specs how the data structure is.

Comment: Poeple upload corrupted images -- perfectly normal -- some try to upload stuff that isn't an image to see how your code reacts (might be an attack vector search), some simply upload faulty files.

Comment: The image is checked to be an image before that switch. Does this mean that the file itself is corrupted?